# Hiding the black window in C++

Tags: c++, c, console, command-prompt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create an Application without a Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224225/create-an-application-without-a-window)
>   [Win32 programming hiding console window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622592/win32-programming-hiding-console-window)

How can I hide the console window that appears when I run my C++ program? The program doesn't output anything to stdout, and I don't need that black window to appear each time I run the program. I don't want it to be minimized I want it to be invisible. Any ideas?

Comment: This is platform-dependent. Are you talking about Windows?

Answer (score 16):

If you want to hide the console you can call [FreeConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on windows

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    FreeConsole();
    //other stuff
}
```

As David mentioned this might flash for a brief second. If you don't want that you can create a [windows service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k985bc9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or a windows gui application and not create a window like below

```
#include <windows.h>

int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    //do stuff here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This still shows the console window for a split second

Comment: FreeConsole is gold! thanks for the tip. I'm fine with a brief flash...

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like the problem is that you are creating a console application. These come with a console by default. They either inherit the console of the process that called them, if it has one, or otherwise create a new console.

You should make your application target the GUI subsystem rather than the console subsystem. This doesn't mean that you have to show any GUI. It's perfectly reasonable and commonplace to make an application that targets the GUI subsytem but does not show any windows.

Comment: Also note that a GUI cannot read from or write to the console (if any) that launched it.

Comment: @David But if I have a requirement of console based app only, but without flickering the console window, can it be achieved?