# I want to make a program without any visual dialog

Tags: c++

I have written a program that reads some information from a file and after processing it, writes it on another file.

However, I don't wanna to see any window appear on my monitor when I open my program, even for a moment. Is there any way to make it invisible?

Comment: Seems windows; and no you can't.

Comment: You have to tell us your OS as well as compiler, IDE etc. However, if it is in Windows and you are using Visual C++, you are probably creating a "console application", which of course opens a console. If you create a windows application, you can choose not to open a window.

Comment: @H2CO3, why is that? I bet I can, why wouldn't he be able?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224225/create-an-application-without-a-window

Comment: It's probably called Windows, because it has got windows popping up, doesn't it? ;) (*edit*: Sorry for that little joke. For a serious answer see below those of Christian and Rango)

Comment: Marcelo Cantos : windows

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about Windows, then what exactly are you seeing? A console window popping up? That happens automatically if you run a console program via the desktop GUI, because a console program is supposed to have a console.

Simply make your application a GUI application... and don't create any windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a Win32 Application.

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    // do whatever you want
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I  did it but i still see a console window !

Comment: @armanradan Are you using GCC? If so, please use gcc -mwindows to create a GUI program.