# How to hide the console window in a Win32 project using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I need to create an exe application with no console window or (any other window) during the start up of the application.

I tried the below for this:

1. Using Visual Studio 2010, created a Win32 Console Application as an Empty Project.
2. Added a header file "stdafx.h" to the project
3. Added a cpp file to the project and added the below code.
4. The project settings are visual stduio default.

   ```
   #include "stdafx.h"
   #include <windows.h>  
   #include "TlHelp32.h"
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
   {

           return 0;
   }
   ```

The above code compiles good.

But if I change the Character Set to "Use Unicode Character Set", I am getting the following compilation error.

> error C2731: 'WinMain' : function cannot be overloaded

I am building the application on a Windows 7 64 bit computer and Visual Studio Build platform as x64.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, when you build with UNICODE in effect then the entrypoint takes a Unicode string for the command line argument.  So that requires a different declaration:

```
  int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
                        LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
```

Or you can use `#include <tchar.h>` so it works either way, not much point to it these days:

```
  int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
                         LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, create a new "EMPTY Project".  Add a new source file named "main.cpp".  Use the following template (assumes you want to build with Unicode):

```
/************
   main.cpp
************/

#define UNICODE 1

#include <windows.h>

int APIENTRY wWinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
                       LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    // Process Return Codes
    const int SUCCESS=0, FAILURE=1;


    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create Windows service instead console app.