# C++ No Window example

Tags: c++, windows

I am using this Code to hide the console window:

C++:

```
void Stealth() 
{ 
  HWND Stealth; 
  AllocConsole(); 
  Stealth = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL); 
  ShowWindow(Stealth,0); 
}
```

It is still showing for a second, so as a task it is very annoying.
A tip was to create a Win32 GUI program with no GUI.
I tried that, but by deleting some parts of the Visual Studio GUI example the code always got corrupt.
Could you please provide an empty GUI program with everything removed, so I can use it?

Comment: probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224225/create-an-application-without-a-window

Comment: Please don't sign your questions. Also, read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The question proposed for duplicate candidate explains how to create a program the does not need a console.

As an alternative, you could create a normal console application, and simply starts it from a shortlink and in the shortlink, you ask for a minimized window (shortlink tab).

It is not really a hiden window, since it exists in the task bar and can be reopened as normal, but I often prefer this. Because if things go wrong, it means that you can open it and look for possible messages, and when things go well, you hardly notice a new console icon in the task bar.