# Run Win32 program without console "silient"

Tags: c++, console, hidden

I´m trying to run my c++ Win32 program without a console. I just want to run the .exe file then Im going for the resultat via txt file that the program creates.

Im using VS2013 and I have search for the web for a way to do this but the only thing i can find is from VS2008 and dosn´t work for me. I need a hand guys.
Best regards P.

Comment: Why, instead of using `cout`, don't you use on out stream?

Comment: I do use out instead of cout, but still I don´t want to have a console window.

Comment: When you create a project, you can select Wind32 project, and when pressing next, you can choose between Console app, Windows app, static lib and dynamic lib. Did you choose Windows application when you created your project?

Comment: I selected Windows application when I created my project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/224225/669576

Comment: @Johnny I tried this already no success

Comment: @PetrusLindblom You must have selected Windows Console Application. That information is in the file header. That sets a thing in the file header that tells windows whether to use the console subsystem or the win32/user subsystem. Console subsystem pops up a console, win32 application does not.

Comment: From a developer perspective, it is a link option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is good enough for me! Thanks guys

```
#include<Windows.h>

int main()
{
Freeconsole();
// Program code goes here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With VS 2013 or Visual Studio from as early as I can remember there is a class called ProcessStartInfo you can pass parameters to. You could create an .NET application that runs your C++ console exe with `ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden` flags. Also use >> results.txt as the parameter. You could also use cmd.exe and pass the exe and it's arguments as the arguments property.

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo start =
      new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();     
start.FileName = @"yourapp.exe";
start.Arguments = @">> results.txt";
start.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Not sure if this is what your wanting, but just a suggestion.

Comment: yeah but the interfaceless c# app could call the C++ executable I was thinking. Not sure it'd work but... he already has VS 2013, so if he could run his already compiled win32 app as a parameter in place of "yourapp.exe", maybe it'd work?

Comment: Is there a way in just regular console based application?